# how to create and use a global variables in WPF (c#)

Tags: c#, wpf

i have an application in WPF (C# ) that have multi users, the user can do different operations using the application but, every user has different access permission i want to create a variable in the first window that contains the name of the user , cause i need to store it in another table in the database ( every time the user do an operation i save his name and the time of this operation in the table ) , so now i don't know how to create a variable that can be used in different windows of the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a global variable in any class like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public static string UserName ="DefaultUser";
    ...
}
```

Then access it from anywhere:

```
MessageBox.Show(YourClass.UserName);
```